# Problems using Halyard to configure GCP as cloud provider in a new Spinnaker installation when my GCP Network is not called 'Default'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spinnaker

I'm using this guidelines:
https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/gce/

When I'm running this line:

```
hal config provider google account add my-gce-account --project $PROJECT  --json-path $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DEST
```

I get an error:

> *Problems in default.provider.google: ! ERROR Network default not found via any configured google*

When I run the entire process in a project that has a 'default' named network, it works fine.

I was not able to find how I say to Halyard that my network has another name.

Could someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, for my setup it turned out that bakery was running in the wrong zone, so expanding on the previous response:

```
$ hal config provider google bakery edit --network <your-custom-network-name>
$ hal config provider google bakery edit --zone <your-zone>
$ sudo hal deploy apply
```

The full spec for options can be found here:
https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/commands/#hal-config-provider-google-bakery-edit

Thanks to Sweeti Bharti's response, it led me to that response :)

Answer (score 1):

@Thiago you might have to go an edit `.hal/config` and modify `network: default` to `network: <your-custom-network-name>` and followed by `hal deploy apply`. We ran into same issue, this is a dirty hack that worked for us.